# 502 error when redirecting stream from another site

Tags: c#, azure, web, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

In my WEB Api 2 controller I want to request file from one site and return this file from my controller. Here is the code

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetLecture()
{            
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://openmedia.yale.edu/cgi-bin/open_yale/media_downloader.cgi?file=/courses/spring11/phil181/mp3/phil181_01_011111.mp3");
    request.Referer = @"http://oyc.yale.edu/courses/";

    var receivedResponse = request.GetResponse();

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);                    
    response.Content = new StreamContent(receivedResponse.GetResponseStream());
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(receivedResponse.ContentType);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "phil181_01_011111.mp3";
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = receivedResponse.ContentLength;

    return response;
}
```

Locally it works fine and I can download the file but when I deploy it to Azure I'm getting 502 Error. Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

[image]

Logging shows that it fails after returning response so no exceptions during method execution.

It's ~50MB file. For smaller files code works fine.

How can I make this code works on Azure for 50 MB files?

Comment: What if you read the whole response (for testing purposes) without streaming it ditectly? Maybe reading response while hosting in azure just fails for some reason?

Comment: It might be because request is taking long time. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503)
Try by downloading small file first.

Comment: @Shah It doesn't look like request is taking long time. Whole method takes less then a second to execute.

Comment: I tried to save it to temp file. It saves stream and when I try to return stream from file it fails same way.

Comment: Based on your code, I could return the image stream from my azure blob storage to the client when deployed to my azure web app.  Does your web app fail all time? Have you tried [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug)?

Comment: Yep, it successfully returns from blob but fails for google drive link or above url. Thanks for pointing to Remote debugging. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Is it taking more than 230 seconds? Are you using a custom VM on Azure or Azure App services?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Azure app service. Method itself takes less then second. Download of stream may take longer then 230 seconds however I get 502 error almost immediately.

Comment: Try using try catch and see if there is some exception?

Comment: No exceptions during method execution. I suppose it fails somewhere in azure internals while passing response to client.

Comment: Did you try on files of different sizes? Does it fail for any size?

Comment: @Evk smaller files work fine

Comment: So seems you are hitting some response size limit. Azure (or maybe something else) sees Content-Lenght header of response and sees it's larger than some limit, so rejects it and returns 502. Unfortunately I have no experience with azure, so that is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I will recommend [configuring remote IIS administration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/08/05/configure-remote-iis-administration-for-microsoft-azure-web-sites/) for your Azure Web App since that will allow you direct access to IIS logs and associated settings. I have a strong feeling that the problem has to do with IIS/ASP.NET limits. You already pointed out that the method completes execution within seconds so this is likely not a timeout problem.

You also mentioned that the code works for smaller file sizes but fails when the size is increased. This points towards [IIS bufferingLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/asp/limits) for your website being set to a small value (or perhaps the default value of ~4 MB). [Here](http://blog.techstacks.com/2012/06/iis75-increase-asp-buffer-limit.html) is a link describing how you can increase this limit to the desired value. Hope this works for you. If it doesn't, I would recommend digging into those IIS logs for your website.

Answer (score 0):

The error message talks about the content, have you tried other content types rather than the one you get here `receivedResponse.ContentType`  ?

You said in previous comments that the error appears with Google drive and above URL, so it mey depends on the returned content type.

Also, you are returning a **stream** not the file as a whole, while specifying `ContentDisposition` to be `"attachment"`.

so maybe "audio/mpeg" will solve it or some other content-type that works will with streams.